# Startup script not running on GCP Compute Engine windows server with autoscaling turned on

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I have a Managed Group in Computer engine on GCP.  Autoscaling is set up and running but when a new server comes on or if I do a "Rolling Replace" the start up script is not being run.  It is a very simple script that makes sure the latest code is running on the website. This is a screenshot from the "Template" that is used to create the new VMs

[image]

If I RDP into the box and run the exact same two lines of code, it works fine.

[image]

Is there something that I need to do before or after the script to make sure that the VM is fully up and ready for the command? Or something else that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a Startup Script in Windows, you need to use a specific key depending on what type of startup up script you would like to run. In your case, you are running cmd commands so in this case you have to replace the key "startup-script" with "windows-startup-script-cmd" within the Template as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances).